# Div doesn't show any elements under it

Tags: css, html

To save your time I'll clarify what I want to say with an image
[image]

My HTML

```
<div align="center"> 
         <div class="img-container">
         <div class="myconatiner">
          <h2>Headline</h2>
          <img src="img/image.png"> 
           <p>Caption</p>
         </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS

```
.img-container { width:100%; background-color:#59cbfc; position:absolute; right:0; left:0; vertical-align:central; }
.img-container h2 { float:left; padding:20px 0 0 0; max-width:500px; text-align:center; }
.img-container p { float:left; padding:10px 0 0 0; max-width:500px; text-align:center; }
.img-container img { float:right; width:500px; height:326px; padding-top:10px; bottom:0; }
.mycontainer { width:100%; max-width:1000px; height:auto; }
```

The problem is that whenever I put any element or div it doesn't show since it's under that `img-container` div.

Comment: That's because your `.img-container` is absolutely positioned. If you want to place something below it, increase it's (the element below `.img-container`) top margin to be equal to or greater than `.img-container`'s height. Also note that there's no `vertical-align:central;` property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @j08691 but I haven't set any height to `.img-container` as you can see. What should I do to keep it `position:absolute;` but with be able to place elements below it.

Comment: Is `.img-container`'s height going to change?

Comment: Sorry I can't fully understand what do you mean by it's going to change but I think no, it's just a constant height.

Comment: So if the height isn't going to change, you can figure out what the height is (trial and error or measuring), and then use that as the top margin for the element that will come below it.

Comment: Ah, I got it .. I'll try that now, thank you

Comment: @j08691 This one worked like a charm as well .. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see the elements below `.img-container` because it has `position:absolute`. This causes the div to cover the elements that are "behind" the div -- i.e. the ones you have placed below it in your source code.

There are two easy solutions to this problem:

- Absolutely [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) the elements below the div.
- Use [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float) or other positioning techniques to position divs on your page. This is probably the better approach as you do not have a `height` for `.img-container`. An example is shown below.

CSS:

```
.img-container {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#59cbfc;
    vertical-align:central;
    float:left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle example using `float` instead of `position:absolute`](http://jsfiddle.net/EegyV/2/).

Comment: Yeah it worked. But, I want to start the `background-color` from 0 pixel `left` and `right` is there any property other than `postion:absolute;` to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @Abd-ElrhmanRizk: Using `float:left` and `width:100%` should do the trick. You may have to add `html, body { width:100%; }` as well, since  percentage widths are relative to the width of the parent element. See my updated JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/EegyV/2/

Comment: :I tried what you mentioned but it didn't work. it still doesn't start from 0px :/ I'll see it now

Comment: @Abd-ElrhmanRizk: Try setting `* { margin: 0; }` or `body, html { margin:0; }`

Comment: Still no success.. BTW I tried `position:absolute;` as you mentioned in the answer and it worked but the new element is placed on the `img-container`

Comment: @Abd-ElrhmanRizk: I'm surprised the float method did not work. Regardless, if you absolutely position your other elements, you will need to place it absolutely below `.img-container`; for example: adding `top: #px` to the new element's style. Otherwise, it will place it at `top:0px` by defualt, just like `.img-container`.